# Run Java applets on Chrome 36 on Linux x86_64

Tags: google-chrome, java

How can I enable or make Java (OpenJDK) available on my Chrome 36 browser? I have installed all 32 and 64 bit (headless) packages as well as the `icedtea-web` package (noarch) and still I can't get Chrome to run Java: *pages always report that Java is not installed*. I remember it worked flawlessly a few months ago and now out of a sudden there's no support. Java runs perfectly fine on Firefox and Midori. My system is running Fedora 20 x86_64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome removed support for certain types of plugins (old NPAPI type). I believe it was around version 35 on Linux.

The Java plugin is NPAPI and currently there is no other type available.
So long story short, chrome does not support the Java plugin available at this moment.

See: http://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation

Comment: You are completely right. I didn't have the correct words to Google it for myself, so thank you so much!

Comment: what a shame I add... I wonder which spooky threats I have risked with a java enabled browser in the past... o_O